# Remove / clear all entities from a contentState

Tags: entity, draftjs

I'm trying to remove all entities from a contentState.

What would be the prefered way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the canonical way is, but I've been able to do it by using `Modifier.applyEntity()`: https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-modifier#applyentity.

You basically need to loop through all the blocks, and use that method on the entire range of text in each block. So something like this:

```
import {Modifier, SelectionState} from 'draft-js';
function clearEntityRanges(contentState){
  contentState.getBlockMap().forEach(block => {
    const blockKey = block.getKey();
    const blockText = block.getText();
    // You need to create a selection for entire length of text in the block
    const selection = SelectionState.createEmpty(blockKey);
    const updatedSelection = selection.merge({
      //anchorOffset is the start of the block
      anchorOffset: 0,
      // focustOffset is the end
      focusOffset: blockText.length
    })
    Modifier.applyEntity(contentState, updatedSelection, null);
  });
  return contentState
}
```